# How to unit test updating meta content in Vue Quasar Meta component with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, quasar-framework

I am trying to unit test updating the meta content of a Vue & Quasar page using the `useMeta` component supplied by Quasar

My test is as follows, I have a `UseMetaComponent` mock vue component, that gets created within a mock `App` component. The `UseMetaComponent` does load, as 'Component Added' is output by the `wrapper.html()` console log.

However, the meta tags are not updated. I have confirmed that this code does function properly in a browser.

```
installQuasarPlugin();

const UseMetaComponent = {
  name: 'UseMetaComponent',
  template: `
    <div>Component Added</div>
  `,
  setup() {
    useMeta({
      title: 'New Title',
      meta: {
        description: {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'test',
        },
      },
    });
  },
};

const App = {
  components: {
    UseMetaComponent,
  },
  template: `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Initial Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="q-app">
      <use-meta-component />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  `,
};

describe('QuasarMetaHandler', (): void => {
  const wrapper = mount(App);

  console.log(wrapper.html());

  it('defaults title Site Name', (): void => {
    const title = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
    console.log(title);
  });
});
```

Is there a way to test updating the meta components?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `nextTick` function from Vue. It allows you to wait for the DOM to update after changes to reactive data. This can help ensure that your test checks the updated meta tags after Vue has had a chance to react to the changes.

This is how you could update your test to wait for changes:

```
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('QuasarMetaHandler', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = mount(App);
    // Waiting for vue to finish updating the DOM
    await nextTick();
  });

  it('updates title to New Title', () => {
    const title = document.title;
    console.log(title);
    expect(title).toBe('New Title');
  });

  it('updates description meta tag', () => {
    const descriptionMetaTag = document.querySelector("meta[name='description']");
    console.log(descriptionMetaTag);
    expect(descriptionMetaTag.content).toBe('test');
  });
});
```

**Also:**

1. Depending on the Quasar's useMeta implementation and the overall setup, you might need to tweak the test to suit the actual behavior of your application.
2. If you are still facing issues, consider adding a package specifically designed for handling head meta tags (like vue-meta) and see if it provides better support for testing these scenarios.

Comment: This solution does not appear to work, I have also made some experimental adjustments, and cannot get the title to update

Comment: 1. Make sure your testing has a full DOM implementation 2. Try using vue-meta 3. Instead of checking global doc, check the wrapper.vm.$meta().refresh() output 4. Also make sure component is mounted and all lifecycle hooks were executed. If all this wont work create a small reproduction of the problem and show it

Answer (score 0):

Testing updates to meta components using Vue Test Utils can be a bit tricky since meta updates are typically managed by the browser and not directly accessible through the DOM.
Here's a potential approach to testing the updating of meta components in your scenario:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { useMeta } from 'quasar';

describe('QuasarMetaHandler', (): void => {
  it('updates meta tags', (): void => {
    // Mount your component
    const wrapper = mount(UseMetaComponent);
const titleElement = document.querySelector('title');
    expect(titleElement.textContent).toBe('New Title');
  });
});
```